# Error filtering template: Notice: unserialize()

Tags: php, magento2

I have this sample:

**CODE PHP:**

```
["conditions_encoded"] => string(324) "a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:3:`140`;]]"
```

I try to unserialize with this code:

```
<?php Zend_Debug::dump(base64_decode(unserialize($block->getConditionsEncoded())));?>
```

but I get this error:

```
Error filtering template: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 324 bytes
```

How can I fix this error? Which do you think would be the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the ` are the problem, try replacing them with double quotes (")

Comment: can you edit my code to understand exactly what you mean? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, this isn't data, serialized with php's `serialize`. To 
 decode the data stored in `conditions_encoded`, you could use the `\Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions` helper, which has an decode method.

I looked again at your serialized data, and it seems, it isn't exactly the format, magento stores in the conditions_encoded var for widgets. But it seems, your given code uses a simple replacement for `{ => [`, `} => ]` and ``` `` => " ```, so you could revert it easily with something like this:

```
$unescaped = str_replace(
    ['[', ']', '`'],
    ['{', '}', '"'],
    $encoded);

$data = unserialize($unescaped);
```

Comment: i get this error Error filtering template: \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions doesn't extends Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper